# How do you automatically select F in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a batch file if I have for example
`%backupcmd% "Desktop\testfile" "%drive%\grab\test"` it pops up with http://prntscr.com/clbmen, how would I designate it in my batch to automatically select F?

Comment: Please add the code of your batch-file and clearly ask for what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably asking about automatically sending `F` to the command as it presents a query to which you need to reply `F` for `File, not Directory`.

The classic method is

```
echo F|yourcommand....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach (there is actually no need to pipe characters into commands)...

For copying a single file, use [`copy`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) rather than [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), because `copy` assumes the target to be a file in such situations:

```
copy "\path\to\a\singe\source\file.txt" "\path\to\destination\file.txt"
```

For multiple source files, `xcopy` is better as it features a `/I` switch -- see `xcopy /?`.